# css - make 2 display:table-row sticky on top of each other

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have this HTML

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell sticky"><span>Header Row 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell sticky"><span>Header Row 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail Row 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail Row 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

It makes the **second Header Row sticky** - just as expected - but what if I want **both Header Rows** to be sticky on top of each other? - so that these 2 rows are always visible when the user scrolls the page?

Comment: For a sticky block, you need to set the `top`. In your case, two stickiness blocks work, but only the first block is hidden, since the second block also has `top: 0`. Set the second block to the same height as the first sticky block. This can be done with `nth-child()`. (I'm sorry for my bad english)

Comment: added DIV and Table base example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to set the `top` for the second sticky block. And this `top` should be equal to the `height` of the first sticky one. You can define each parent of a sticky block using pseudo class `:nth-child()`.

**30px** is the *approximate* height of the first sticky block.

Take a look at the css code, and you will understand what I mean.

```
.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  background: red;
}

.row:nth-child(1) .sticky {
  top: 0px;
} 

.row:nth-child(2) .sticky {
  top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks s.kuznetsov for your answer - I got it to work just perfect in my real world App.

Answer (score 0):

I have added both the headers in a single sticky rows.

```css
.table {
    display: table;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sticky1, .sticky2, sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell sticky1"><span>Header Row 1</span>
        <div class="cell sticky2"><span>Header Row 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Detail Row 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have different approach. I suggest `table` base structure instead of using `div` base structure.

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
tr.red th {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
tr.green th {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
tr.purple th {
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}
th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="red">
      <th>Header Row 1</th>
      <th>Header Row 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header Detail 1.</td>
      <td>Header Detail 2.</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**If you still want to use `DIV` structure, here is an example.**

```css
.wrap {
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 10em auto 20em;
  max-width: 960px;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /*overscroll-behavior: contain;*/
}

.scenes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.track {
  flex: 1 0 calc(22% + 7px);
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.track + .track {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.heading {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #efefef;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.entry {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  height: 8em;
  padding: 1em;
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .track {
    flex: 1 0 calc(50% + 7px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="scenes">
    <div class="track">
      <div class="heading">Heading 1</div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="heading">Heading 2</div>
      
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="heading">Heading 3</div>
      
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="heading">Heading 4</div>
      
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="heading">Heading 5</div>
      
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="heading">Heading 6</div>
      
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="heading">Heading 7</div>
      
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a real table, you would use a `thead` or `tbody` or `tfoot` tag to group a few rows together to stick them. `table-row-group` is avalaible via CSS to mimic a `tbody` behavior :

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display
>
> **table-row-group**
>
> **table-header-group**
>
> **table-footer-group**
>
> These elements behave like  HTML elements.

possible example below keeping the table-layout and dealing with groups of rows instead individuals rows :

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

/*new */
.header-row-group {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight:bold;
}
/* end new */
.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="header-row-group sticky"><!-- header row group added -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell "><span>Header Row 1</span></div> <div class="cell">header Row 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell "><span>Header Row 2</span></div> <div class="cell">Wider Cell on  Row 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div> 
      <div class="cell">Detail cell</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```